# Is it possible to do ".value +=" in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Classic javascript:

```
var myvar = document.getElementById("abc");
abc.value += "test";
abc.value += "another test";
```

Jquery:

```
$("#abc").val($("#abc").val()+"test");
$("#abc").val($("#abc").val()+"another test");
```

Is there a way to make my Jquery prettier, maybe with a hidden += function that I could use? I know that .val() is not an attribute, but I feel there must be a way to make this code more beautiful to look at...

Something like this would be great:

```
 $("#abc").valueAttribute += "test"
 $("#abc").val().content += "test"
 $("#abc").val().add("test")
```

Comment: Be careful with any solution that uses `.value` (including the first part of my answer). It will only work for `<input>` elements. You may end up pulling your hair out one day if abc becomes a `<textarea>`.

Comment: yes I know, it will only be for input elements :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text to input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field)

Comment: I wish Stack Overflow had a feature where the author of an old accepted answer could propose moving the check mark to a newer answer. In this case, Felix's answer is better.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney I changed the accepted answer to Felix's :)

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney *there's* a feature request for you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.4, it is possible to pass a function to [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) which gets the current value as second argument:

```
$("#abc").val(function(i, val) {
    return val + "test";
});
```

Answer (score 24):

You could go back to the original DOM element.

```
 $("#abc").get(0).value += "test";
```

Otherwise, you'd have to write a plugin

```
 $.fn.appendVal = function (newPart) {
   return this.each(function(){ $(this).val( $(this).val() + newPart); });
 };

 $("#abc").appendVal("test");
```

Comment: Plugin is nice solution, but shouldn't it do return this.each(function(){ $(this).val( $(this).val + newPart); }); --- preserve chain ability and apply to multiple elements if needed?

Comment: Yes, gnarf, that's much better. Thanks! I rewrote the plugin using your code.

Comment: Cool - Deleting my answer then!

Comment: one last comment on the plugin... return this.each instead of $(this).each - "this" will be a jquery object already - no need to pass it through the jquery function again.

Answer (score 2):

I've never come across anything like that, doesn't mean it doesn't exist though.

I usually just store val() in a temporary variable and do the manipulation on that, then call val(temp) in a separate line.  It spreads the operation out to three or more lines, but it's still more readable than `.val(.val() + "")`, IMO.  It also scales better than +=, if you have a more complicated expression to do to the value.

```
var temp = $(".abc").val();
temp += "test";
$(".abc").val(temp);
```

Comment: True, it would look better. I don't worry about scalling since it's a pretty simple function and there is no reason for it to evolve too much.

Answer (score 2):

`$()` returns a selection; it doesn't return the actual resulting object (although in practice, it simply returns a list of the actual objects). If you want to mutate the object's `.value` property, you can do this:

```
$('.abc').each(function(){ this.value += foo; });
```

If you like, you can create functions that operate on selections, such as `.add()`, which could be implemented like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ add: function(k,v) { this[k](this[k]()+v); } });
```

which can then be used like this:

```
$('.abc').add('val', foo);
```

...but I don't think this is any better than using `$().each()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
        $.fn.valInc = function(vadd)
        {
            var val = $(this).val() + '' + vadd;
            $(this).val(val);
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $(function(){
        $("#tst").valInc('test 2');
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='tst' value="test" />
</body>
</html>
```