# Jquery: Append a Form Input Value (.val)

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying trying to write a string of multiple values depending on whether specific checkboxes are checked. i.e.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  if ($('#box1').attr('checked')) {
    $('#MyInput').val('box1 ');
    alert('1');
  }

  if ($('#box2').attr('checked')) {
    $('#MyInput').val('box2 ');
    alert('2');
  }
});
```

The return I am looking for in this case would be '1 2', however only the second value is written in the input field.

The alerts tell me that both events in the argument are firing. Is there another method for appending values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do ".value +=" in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224133/is-it-possible-to-do-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.val()` does not append.. it sets the value to whatever you pass, overwriting the previous value.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

var myInput = $('#MyInput').val('')[0];


if($('#box1').attr('checked')){
    myInput.value += 'box1 ';
    alert('1');
    }

if($('#box2').attr('checked')){
     myInput.value += 'box2 ';
    alert('2');
    }

else {}

});
```

---

And if you have multiple checkboxes that you want all of their values added to the myInput element if they are checked you can add a class to all of them and just do

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var myInput = $('#MyInput').val('')[0];
  $('.common-class-to-all:checked').each(function(){
     myInput.value += this.value + ' ';
  });
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/SQcGq/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a typo? In the first `if` you check the "checked" **value**, in the second `if` you check for the "checked" **attribute**

In case you use jQuery 1.6+ you should use `$('#box1').prop("checked")`

Check/modify this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/45WgD/

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var values = [];
    $("#box1, #box2").filter(":checked").each(function(i, box){
        values.push($(box).attr("id"));
    });

    $('#MyInput').val(values.join(" "));
```

});

Comment: thanks for catching that. typo was in the question only. edited.

Comment: did the prop() fix it or still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Give the boxes a class like `boxes`, and use the [`map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to get a collection of the values, the [`get()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to convert it to an Array, and `.join()` to join them into a string.

Then set the resulting string once as the value using the [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var values = $('.boxes').map(function() {
        return this.checked ? this.id : '';
    }).get().join(' ');

    $('#MyInput').val( values );

});
```

---

**EDIT:** The requirement was to use a string equal to the ID for the result. Fixed. Thanks to [@Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377464/bryan) for the heads up.

Comment: +1 I like this solution. The only thing I'd change is that I think he's using the IDs here, so you could do `return this.id` instead. Nitpicking, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the value of `MyInput` each time. `.val` does not add on to the value of the input field, it replaces it.

```
var value = [];

if ($('#box1').prop('checked')) {
  value.push('box1');
}

if ($('#box2').prop('checked')) {
  value.push('box2');
}

$("#MyInput").val(value.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `$('#MyInput').val('box1 ');` overwrites the value of the textbox, which is why you're only seeing the second value, this should work:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

  var new_val = '';

  if($('#box1').is(':checked')){
    new_val += 'box1 ';
  }

  if($('#box2').is(':checked')){
    new_val += 'box2 ';
  }

  $('#MyInput').val(new_val);

else {}

});
```

Comment: works great thanks! but Gaby anticipated my need for multiple check boxes below.