# I can't use val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with getting the val of an input element I have.
You see, I don't know if my code is wrong, but my Visual Studio (legal) doesn't even try to help me complete what I want to type. All it gives me is Value() and ValueOf().

The part of the code I'm using:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(start);
{
    $("#b1").click(toev);
}
function toev() {
    var value = $("#b1").val();
    $("#output").append(value);
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="output"/>
<td><input type="button" id="b1" value="1" /></td>
```

Comment: `$("#output").val(value)`?

Comment: And `$(document).ready(start);
{
    $("#b1").click(toev);
}` is invalid or at least not what you mean.

Comment: Others have pointed out the issues with your code, but to address "_Visual Studio (legal) doesn't even try to help me complete what I want to type_" -- Visual Studio doesn't always have perfect intellisense for javascript, and definitely not for jQuery, though 2012 is much improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yS8tw/

Few things to note:

- Use of `document.ready`
- Use of `Val`

**Also** I like this `appendVal` function: http://jsfiddle.net/5R7eZ/ - [Is it possible to do ".value +=" in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224133/is-it-possible-to-do-value-in-jquery)

Rest should fit the needs `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#b1").click(toev);
  });

  function toev() {
      var value = $("#b1").val();
      alert(value);
      $("#output").val(value);
  }
```

**With AppendVal**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#b1").click(toev);
  });

  function toev() {
      var value = $("#b1").val();

      $("#output").appendVal(value);
  }

 $.fn.appendVal = function (newPart) {
   return this.each(function(){ this.value += newPart; });
 };
```

Comment: Thank you Tats! This helped me get it working! I was a bit confused with the $(document).ready part. I was thought it so fast (I'm in college) that it's all a bit much right now. Thank you again! And also to everyone else who answered.

Comment: @user3092948 Glad it helped you! Have fun! `:)` All it matters is to learn the basics, rest just flows in if you keen. You will be saweeet yo!

Comment: Thanks for indirectly pointing out I didn't have an username! And yes indeed, but the problem is, right now in College we are busy covering the basics for Linux, C#, jquery (and javascript, html, css) all at once and it gets very confusing / hard to keep up with everything. But thanks for helping me again. I hope I can get this down before finals.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append content to an `<input>` element because it cannot have content. Perhaps you meant

```
  $('#output').val(value);
```

to set its value.