# How to create a delimited string dynamically with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a dynamic form builder where table rows can be dragged, dropped, reordered and so on. Most of this is working but when it comes to deleting rows how would I created an array or set of values that I could post back to the php script that I am using to update the database.

The way I am going to handle it is create a delimited string and post this back.

How would I go about creating the the string dynamically by appending a value like the following: 23| every time the user clicks a button? For example the if user click the button 3 times the sting would be 23|25|26| and then when they clicked save that value could be posted back to be processed.

This is the code I have for the delete function so far but its only removing the table rows and not actually generating the string.

```
$(".reMove").live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();


     var al = $(this).attr('rel');


    $("#form1").find(".del").val(al);


    e.preventDefault();

    sortt();

});
```

Comment: Did you try $("fieldId").val($("fieldId").val()+"|"+(cnt++))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text to input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array:

```
var deletions = [];

// When deleting
deletions.push(value);

// When sending to your PHP script, create a string via Array#join
var deletionsString = deletions.join("|");
```

Alternately, if you like, you can just use a string and append to it:

```
var deletions = "";

// When deleting
deletions += "|" + value;

// When sending to your PHP script
if (deletions.length > 0) {
    deletions = deletions.substring(1); // Skip the leading "|"
}
```

...but I prefer the array route.

Comment: @Pointy: When sending the array to PHP? Yeah, that's a good option, if the OP's open to changing the format. Mind you, there are still plenty of browsers that don't have `JSON.stringify`, so it's another script to add (unless they really are numbers, in which case it's trivial to create the JSON by hand).

Comment: will try the above solutions and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've got a form here. You could dynamically create a hidden input:

```
var $input = $('<input/>')
    .attr('type', 'hidden')
    .attr.('name', 'del[]')
    .val(al);
$("#form1").append($input);
```

After posing this form back you could simply delete all records from $_POST['del'] array.
Maybe this is the solution you're looking for?