# How to append a textfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

`split_values1` is an array and it contents some values, all i want to do is  add those values to the textfield with a `,` separating them.

```
for(var i = 0; i < split_values1.length; i++) {
   $('#teach_subjects').value += split_values1[i]", ";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text to input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field)

Comment: Why do you think string concatenation is performed with `&`? jQuery objects don't have a `value` property. jQuery's documentation os quite good, it's the first thing you should have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join` on your array and `val` to set textfield value:

```
$('#teach_subjects').val(split_values1.join(', '));
```

Comment: @JackalopeZero Just call me Lucky Luke :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$('#teach_subjects').val(split_values1.join(", "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var value = split_values1.join(", ");
$('#teach_subjects').val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery I would do this.

```
var val = $('#teach_subjects').val();
for(var i = 0; i < split_values1.length; i++) {
   val += split_values1[i] + ", ";
}
$('#teach_subjects').val(val);
```

It's a bad idea for performance reasons to constantly update a value in the DOM, so I used string concatenation.

**As others have stated `join` might be a better choice.**

Comment: Superb, thanks! I know it was a simple one for you, but i am new to using javascript! Thanks again.

Comment: -1 : There will be a trailing ', ' at the end of the textfield.

Comment: @sinsedrix - what if they need it?

Comment: @DanielA.White The OP asked for a separator, not an end of value character.