# Add value to hidden input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am dynamically adding input fields and I want to add a variation of those values of the input fields to hidden input array but I am struggling to do so. I have one hidden input in the html page:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="center_ids[]" value=""/>
```

And the jQuery I am using to add the value I want is the value returned from my AJAX method:

```
    $(".autocomp_centers").autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:'/suggest_centers',
            maxHeight:400,
            width:252,
            minChars:2,
            onSelect: function(value, data){ $("input[name='center_ids']").push(data) }
    });
```

But this does not add to the hidden input field. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: yor answer is [here][1], try this for your function


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be carefull with the name of you input. Your input is named `center_ids[]` and not `center_ids`.

```
$(".autocomp_centers").autocomplete({ 
    serviceUrl:'/suggest_centers',
        maxHeight:400,
        width:252,
        minChars:2,
        onSelect: function(value, data){
            $("input[name='center_ids[]']").val(data);
        }
});
```

Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: WOW! Bad selector by me. Thanks for helping.