# Adding an emoji to input field when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to insert the emoji(s) into my input field called `#usermsg` when it is clicked.

The emoji does not show up in the input field.

I have added `.clone()` to the jQuery function so that the emoji would not disappear when clicked.

[image]

HTML emoji:

```
<a id="smiley" title="smiley" href="#" >&#128515;</a>
```

HTML input field:

```
<input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg"/>
```

jQuery function:

```
//Add emoji when clicked
$("#smiley").click(function(){
    $('#smiley').clone().append('#usermsg');
  });
```

I've tried adding `.val();` after the `.append('#usermsg');` However this still does not work for me.

If someone could lead me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: `$('#usermsg').val($('#smiley').html());`

Comment: This works, thank you. However when clicked multiple times it only shows one emoji in the input text. Is it possible have it insert one emoji per click?

Comment: append the value instead of set it ;)

Comment: @Alexis did you mean     $('#usermsg').append().val($('#smiley').html()); It still does the same for me.

Comment: @Sean take a look on this post :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841722/append-text-to-input-field

Comment: @Alexis Thank you for the quick response, I checked out the post and got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer with help from @guradio and @Alexis

Change:

```
$('#smiley').clone().append('#usermsg');
```

To:

```
$('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $('#smiley').html());
```